# Is it possible to generate/draw on texture with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Can't google anything. Actually it is quite few information about this new framework.
Only thing I could find is the applying Core Image filter to a texture. But I guess to draw simple rectangle above the image I need to write own CI filter..

Does anybody know something on topic?

Comment: The answers here are correct ways to "draw" basic shapes. The docs for SKNode are clear about more complex drawing: "Unlike views, you cannot create SKNode subclasses that perform custom drawing."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you need is a rectangle, use @Kex's solution.

In general, you can create a texture from any UIImage or CGImage. `[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship.png"]` is really just a convenience to `[SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spaceship.png"]]`

So to do some custom drawing into a texture, you can use, for example:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(256, 256));
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[SKColor yellowColor] setFill];
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(64, 64, 128, 128));

UIImage *textureImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:textureImage];
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];

[self addChild:sprite];
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, thats what was curious about. Should work for me.

Comment: Is not platform independent.

Comment: @Jonny since this question was tagged with ios, it doesn't require a solution that also works in osx. That said, I'd love to see a cross-platform solution added as an answer, since that would be useful to have for reference.

Comment: Technically you are right about the tag. I am currently porting a cocos2d iOS game to Sprite Kit (OS X) and there are lots of assumptions of iOS everywhere where there are Sprite Kit code. For that reason it's just handier to stay within the framework as much as possible.

Comment: For OSX: NSImage *textureImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(256, 256)];
        [textureImage lockFocus];
        [[SKColor yellowColor] setFill];
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:NSMakeRect(64, 64, 128, 128)] fill];
        [textureImage unlockFocus];
        
        SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:textureImage];
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];

Answer (score 3):

Textures are just raw graphic representations, I won't solve this with them.

I'd create a sprite from the texture, then a second rectangle sprite with a given size (e.g. 100x100) & I'll add it to the original one at a given position (e.g. `CGPointZero`).

```
SKSpriteNode *rectSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor magentaColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
rectSprite.position = CGPointZero;
[originalSprite addChild:rectSprite];
```

That way the the rectangle will be a part of the sprite & all the transformations/actions to the parent sprite (the one with the texture) would apply to it too.